# Removing .svn folders from project for deployment

Tags: svn, deployment, tortoisesvn

I'm using subversion (TortoiseSVN) and I want to remove the .svn folders from my project for deployment, is there an automated way of doing this using subversion or do I have to create a custom script for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has an export function. This will create the entire SVN tree elsewhere without the `.svn` folders.

Also, a lot of FTP clients have filtering, which you can add `.svn` to just in case you forget one day.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a tortoise solution preferrably. I'm using filezilla, does that have filtering?

Comment: Check out FireFTP if Filezilla doesn't have what you want.

Comment: Tortoise can do an export.  Right-click in windows explorer, TortoiseSVN > Export.

Comment: @glenc Isn't that exactly what my answer is?

Comment: @public static - Yes, Filezilla has filters. Click View > Filters, and you can choose to ignore SVN directories, "useless Explorer files", etc.

Comment: keep in mind that after doing an export, there is no way to do an update.  The closest thing you could do at that point is re-export

Answer (score 30):

Use

```
svn export <url-to-repo> <dest-path>
```

It gets just the source, nothing else. Look in *[svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)* (in *Version Control with Subversion*) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

No need for a script.  As suggested, use the Export command:

- Right click on the top level of your
  working copy.
- Open the TortoiseSVN sub-menu
- Select Export
- Follow on screen dialogs.

Comment: Voted up for the hokie logo (and the better answer) . Go Hokies :)

Answer (score 8):

But if you don't want to use svn export (for whatever reason)...

```
find /path/to/project/root -name '.svn' -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

On a computer:

```
rsync -avz --exclude=".svn" /yourprojectwithsvninside/ /yourprojectwithoutsvninside/
```

From the repository:

```
svn export http://yourserver/svn/yourproject/ ./yourproject/
```

Answer (score 0):

public static: yes FileZilla has filename filtering. Look under View -> Filename Filters. I checked in v3.1.1

I think most FTP clients have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista / 7: turn on view hidden folders and files. In the search box (top right in a Windows Explorer window), write `.svn`. All `.svn` folders will show at top, delete them all and turn hide files back on.

Answer (score -1):

Do `svn export <url>` to export a clean copy without .svn folders.

Answer (score -1):

Use the export feature.